# Disable networking on boot / permanently

Tags: centos, networking

Using a lot of CentOS 7 hosts on a very small subnet. I use only a small portion of the hosts at each time. The other portion of the hosts are powered off. However, occasionally the powered off hosts are booted accidentally and cause a duplicate IP situation.

Considering that I can't change the working procedure, I want to disable the networking completely on the powered off hosts if they are accidentally booted. I can change the `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts` for each interface, but the names of interfaces vary between hosts and the number of interfaces is ~6 for each host.

So, how do I disable **all** networking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried following on few VM's. It's probably overkill but you might try it.

```bsh
for i in network.target network-online.target NetworkManager.service  NetworkManager-wait-online.service network.service; do 
systemctl disable $i
systemctl mask $i
done
```

After it VM's started without networking. Some notes:

- Masked units must be unmasked before used.
- I tried this only on CentOS 7 vms (libvirt && virtualbox vagrant images).
- In the old days you could just set runlevel to multi-user (2, one without networking :)), but systemd (according to my knowledge) don't have a similar target (runlevel).

**Edit:**

As mentioned @GAD3R -  NetworkManager-wait-online.service now is included

Comment: Fixed. I don't know If I could mention your profile in answer the `@` in comments works, but not for answers :(.